# Debian 12 + AWS VPN client

Tags: debian, aws

I got debian 12

I am trying to set AWS VPN client version 3.4.0

```
# apt show awsvpnclient
Package: awsvpnclient
Version: 3.4.0
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: misc
Maintainer: AWS VPN Client
Installed-Size: unknown
Download-Size: unknown
APT-Manual-Installed: yes
APT-Sources: /var/lib/dpkg/status
Description: AWS VPN Client for Ubuntu 18.04
```

When I started I am getting

```
$ /opt/awsvpnclient/AWS\ VPN\ Client %u

(AWS VPN Client:621879): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 13:52:46.193: gtk_tree_model_iter_nth_child: assertion 'n >= 0' failed

(AWS VPN Client:621879): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 13:52:46.193: gtk_list_store_get_path: assertion 'iter->stamp == priv->stamp' failed
No usable version of libssl was found
Aborted
```

AWS Could be still libssl 1.1 ?

Any chance to have this lib for Debian 12

Answer (score 1):

I ended up installing libssl1.1 from Debian 11

```
$ wget wget http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1n-0+deb11u5_amd64.deb
$ dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.1n-0+deb11u5_amd64.deb
```